# Formula to use to get desired result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 2 tables. `Table 1` has raw data, `Table 2` is what I'm using as a report. Can anyone suggest a formula, to be used in column `D` in `Table 2`, to pull all the negative amounts from `Table 1`, based on account number?

For a better understanding please refer to the image below:

[image: Sheet]

Comment: Did the VENDOR in table 2 you need to enter manually?

Comment: I might recommend changing your data structure to a tall table with 3 columns: `vendor, property, amount`. That might give you greater flexibility with your data.

Comment: adding on a 4th column with account, then a pivot table with appropriate filtering would be an option. No need for formulas.

Comment: hav u tried https://exceljet.net/functions/xmatch-function ? (pls share if it works/not)

Answer (score 0):

In the attached file, you will find the solution based on sumifs, index, match.

**Sumifs** does the conditional addition for the specified account number.
**Index** and **Match** helps to locate the column(propety) name.

[Attachment](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Apu-kp1rmkE7mGtd-v2203-DqPYN?e=m3q8hC)

Example:
=SUMIFS(INDEX($B$3:$F$7,,MATCH($A12,$B$2:$F$2,0)),$A$3:$A$7,B12)

[image: For your ref.]